# Integration test for Spring Batch failing because of thread execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch project. The goal is to perform integration tests on individual steps, which are present inside a Spring Job.

I'm using a JobLauncherTestUtils to launch the step. However, when this util launches the steps, it runs it in a separate thread. Once the thread finishes execution, there should be some value assigned to `jobExecution.getStepExecutions()`.

**PROBLEM:** For some reason, even before the thread finish execution, the test goes to the next line  `List<StepExecution> actualStepExecutions = new ArrayList<>(jobExecution.getStepExecutions())`, where `jobExecution.getStepExecutions()` is currently null, and hence the test fails with `NullPointerException` and `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` - marked in the test class below.

**QUESTION:** Is there any graceful way to wait for the Step execution THREAD to finish and then move on to the next lines in the test for validation?

**CODE:**

Integration test class:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "master"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {InhouseClass3.class, InhouseClass1.class, InhouseClass2.class})
public class BatchJobIntegrationTest {

    private static final String Param1 = "someParam";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hikariDatasource")
    DataSource hikariDatasource;

    @Autowired
    Job BatchJob;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    JobExecution jobExecution;

    @Autowired
    CreateDirectoryTasklet createDirectoryTasklet;

    JobParameters jobParameters;

    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        String startTimestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now()).toString();
        jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(Param1, startTimestamp)
                .toJobParameters();

        jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(BatchJob);
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    }


    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void TaskletToTest_Test() {
        jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("loadTaskletToTest", jobParameters);

        List<StepExecution> actualStepExecutions = new ArrayList<>(jobExecution.getStepExecutions());
        // ERROR: jobExecution.getStepExecutions() is NULL. 

        ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = actualStepExecutions.get(0).getExitStatus();
        // ERROR: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

        assertEquals("loadGdxClaims", actualStepExecutions.get(0).getStepName());
        assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, actualJobExitStatus);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    // This is my workaround to make my above test run. 
    // I added a sleep for 2 seconds. But this doesn't look like an ideal way, coz what 
    // if the launchstep thread running the tasklet took more than 2 seconds? 
    void loadGDXClaimTaskletTest_Working_() {
        jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("createDirectory", jobParameters);
        boolean counter = true;
        while(counter) {
            if (jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size()!=0 ) {
                List<StepExecution> actualStepExecutions = new ArrayList<>(jobExecution.getStepExecutions());

                ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = actualStepExecutions.get(0).getExitStatus();
                log.info("------- step executions : {}", actualStepExecutions);
                assertEquals("createDirectory", actualStepExecutions.get(0).getStepName());
                assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, actualJobExitStatus);
                counter = false;
            } else {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Tasklet Step to test:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TaskletToTest implements Tasklet {

    private final InhouseService inhouseService;

    public TaskletToTest(InhouseService inhouseService) {
        this.inhouseService = inhouseService;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException, IllegalJobNameException, JSchException, IOException {
        log.info("TaskletToTest before");
        inhouseService.retry();
        log.info("TaskletToTest after");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Batch job with the list of steps which needs to be tested:

```
@Slf4j
@Profile("master")
@Configuration
public class MasterConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Bean(name = "BatchJob")
    public Job remoteChunkingJob(TaskletStep someOtherTasklet,
                                 TaskletStep loadTaskletToTest,
                                 JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("extract gdx load")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())     
                .listener(jobExecutionListener)
                .start(someOtherTasklet) 
                .next(loadTaskletToTest)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    TaskletStep loadTaskletToTest(TaskletToTest taskletToTest) {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("loadTaskletToTest").tasklet(taskletToTest).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a JobLauncherTestUtils to launch the step. However, when this util launches the steps, it runs it in a separate thread.

> PROBLEM: For some reason, even before the thread finish execution, the test goes to the next line

`JobLauncherTestUtils` uses a `JobLauncher` to launch jobs and steps. So depending on the `JobLauncher` implementation you use, you can run jobs/steps in the current thread or in a separate thread.

You did not share which `JobLauncher` is autowired in your test, but you seem to have defined a job launcher based on a asynchronous `TaskExecutor` implementation. That's why your job/step is executed in the background here:

```
// This returns immediately with an asynchrnous TaskExecutor
// However, with a synchronous TaskExectuor it will block waiting for the step to finish 
jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("loadTaskletToTest", jobParameters);

List<StepExecution> actualStepExecutions = new ArrayList<>(jobExecution.getStepExecutions());
```

So you need to check which `JobLauncher` (typically a `SimpleJobLauncher` with a synchronous or asynchronous `TaskExecutor`) is autowired in your test.

Comment: How can I make the TaskExecutor synchronous in that case?

Comment: You need to set a synchronous `TaskExecutor` implementation on your `JobLauncher`, like `SyncTaskExecutor` which is used by default, see Javadocs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.html. You are autowiring the JobLauncher in your test class but did show how it is created and in which context it is defined. So you need to make sure that that injected JobLauncher is based on a synchronous task executor.